# Why Does my app Closing Automatically when i run on AVD?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

When i am trying to run my app on AVD, it's closing automatically without any error notification. I am a new developer and a new community member also. Here's the java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//initializing WebView
private WebView mwebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //WebView
    mwebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //improve webView performance
    mwebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    mwebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mwebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);


    mwebView.loadUrl("http://www.kknlive.com");
    //force links open in webview only
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_video) {
        // Handle the camera action
        mwebView.loadUrl("");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_society) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_technology) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_sports) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("");
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.kknlive.com")) {
            //open url contents in webview
            return false;
        } else {
            //here open external links in external browser or app
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }
    //ProgressDialogue
    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Please wait..");
        pd.setMessage("Page is Loading..");
        pd.show();
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        pd.dismiss();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
//goto previous page when pressing back button

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mwebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mwebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to take a look in the logcat, there's probably something there that will tell you what's going on

Comment: add the logcat message also

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Please have a look at [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) to get started on troubleshooting problems like this. It will also help us help you as some more details would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your layout has already an action bar, and you set it in the code, so make sure that your `appTheme` in style.xml inherited from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```